# Responding to "Cheers"

Tags: word-usage

I was chatting with one of our clients. He said to me:

> Cheers.

What should I say in response? Should I say *cheers* too?
I know he is saying that to encourage me.

Comment: Why do you believe this was said as encouragement?

Comment: Because He has assigned me some work to do.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Depends on context - but they're all informal, so there are no hard and fast rules.

If you were in a bar, and had just clinked glasses, the appropriate response would be 'cheers' or some other glass clinking epithet (slianche, salut, bottoms up, etc).
If you had just given something to the other person - including information, an answer, etc, then 'cheers' would be a way of thanking you, and you could reply with 'no problem', 'you're welcome', or even just acknowledge the thanks with a nod of your head.
If it was the end of the conversation, then 'cheers' is being used to say good bye. In this instance you could use, 'see you later' or some similar farewell.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on culture or region as well as context, "cheers" can also mean "goodbye", in which case you would simply respond with "cheers" yourself.

Where I live in South Africa, for example, this is the most common meaning of the word.

Answer (score 2):

I have worked with UK and Australia folks for over a decade. Even stayed there for sometime. I guess this qualifies me to answer it in someway.
Cheers is an informal term which during a conversation is being said in the end , which translates as "good bye" or " see ya"  or " catch you later" , there's no fixed reply for this. Though you can respond like you do when someone says "bye" , you can say "cheers mate" as well, you can say " cheers" simply, you can also say "bye","see ya later" "see ya around" and such phrases which you use for a response of bye.
Hope that helps.

So .. cheers mate ..